# Using pyodbc to connect to sybase gives Request to start/stop database denied (-75)

Tags: sybase, pyodbc

Below is my configuration:
Windows 7 x64 running ActiveState Python 2.7.2.5 (64 bit)
Pyodbc 2.1.8
SQL Anywhere 12 driver 12.00.01.3924.

When I try to connect to my sybase database, I get the below error:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={'+driver+'};HOST='+host+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';PORT='+port)
```

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL
>   Anywhere]Request to start/stop database denied (-75)
>   (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Request
>   to start/stop database denied (-75)')

I have tried this with different versions of Pyodbc. I also tried with 32 bit versions of Python and Pyodbc, but was not successful. Googling around gave me nothing concrete, though the problem has been around for some time.

How do I connect seamlessly? I have seen it working some time back on Windows XP, but I do not remember the python and pyodbc versions now. I tried on Windows XP with the same set of above but i get the same error. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm landing on this page every time I google for "pyodbc sybase example" and every time I have to re-invent the answer, so let me just post what actually worked.

Tested on py2.7-Linux, py2.7-win and py3.5-win. Since this question is now 3 years old I could only test it on somewhat later version of pyodbc 4.0.17 (from both pypi and conda) and Sybase ASE 15.

It's mostly based on Brian's answer (thanks Bryan!), but to get the "Tadam!" effect you need to pass the port separately:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=host, port=port, 
                      database=database, uid=username, pwd=password)
```

To get list of drivers, run:

```
pyodbc.drivers()
```

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I get this error: `pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found (-100) (SQLDriverConnect)')` Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The connection string attributes don't match anything I see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/) or [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/asa-odbc/) for Sybase, but I also don't have an instance to test, so take the following with a grain of salt.

Try this syntax to using keywords for the connect method so you don't have to keep up with Sybase-specific attributes:

```
server = "{0}:{1}".format(host, port)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=server, database=database,
                      uid=username, pwd=password)
```

Also note that I'm combining the host and port as formatted in this [example](http://www.connectionstrings.com/asa-odbc/specific-port/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in a Windows 7 machine to connect to sybase database using pyodbc

1. Install Sybase ASE ODBC driver (Check with your IT whether they have this driver)
2. Install Python27 32 bit (I installed the Anaconda distribution Anaconda2-5.3.1-Windows-x86.exe)
3. setup DSN (create new data source using Sybase ASE ODBC driver). Get all the required parameter from appropriate personnel.
4. Test connect to make sure it connects to sybase database you are looking for.
5. Here is the sample python code that worked after doing all the above steps.

import pyodbc

syb_con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=yourDSNname', uid='username', pwd='password')

cursor = syb_con.cursor()

cursor.execute("select count(*) from tbl_name)